# PySpark: use one column to index another (udf of two columns?)

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

**(Edited Feb 14th)**

Let's say I have a Spark (PySpark) dataframe with the following schema:

```
root
 |-- myarray: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- myindices: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: integer (containsNull = true)
```

It looks like:

```
+--------------------+----------+
|          myarray   | myindices|
+--------------------+----------+
|                 [A]|    [0]   |
|              [B, C]|    [1]   |
|        [D, E, F, G]|   [0,2]  |
+--------------------+----------+
```

How can I use the second array to index the first?

My goal is to create a new dataframe which would look like:

```
+--------------------+----------+------+
|          myarray   | myindices|result|
+--------------------+----------+------+
|                 [A]|    [0]   |  [A] |
|              [B, C]|    [1]   |  [C] |
|        [D, E, F, G]|   [0,2]  | [D,F]|
+--------------------+----------+------+
```

(It is safe to assume that the contents of `myindices` are always guaranteed to be within the cardinality of `myarray` for the row in question, so there are no out-of-bounds problems.)

It appears that the `.getItem()` method only works with single arguments, so I might need a UDF here, but I know of no way to create a UDF that has more than one column as input. Any solutions, with or without UDFs?

Comment: df.withColumn('item', df['myarray'].getItem(df['myposition']))

Comment: @zhangtong this should be an answer, not a comment.

Comment: @zhangtong : thanks; unfortunately my actual need is a little more complicated. I have edited the question to make this clearer. Can you please look at the reformulated question and see if you have any suggestions?

Comment: @xenocyon see below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as f

rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize([(['A'], [0]), (['B', 'C'], [1]), (['D', 'E', 'F'], [0, 2])])
df = spark.createDataFrame(rdd, ['myarray', 'myindices'])
my_UDF = f.UserDefinedFunction(lambda x, y: map(lambda z: x[z], y), returnType=ArrayType(StringType()))
res = df.withColumn('result', my_UDF(df['myarray'], df['myindices']))
res.show(truncate=False)

output:
+---------+---------+------+
|myarray  |myindices|result|
+---------+---------+------+
|[A]      |[0]      |[A]   |
|[B, C]   |[1]      |[C]   |
|[D, E, F]|[0, 2]   |[D, F]|
+---------+---------+------+
```

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly and is a neat example of a UDF taking two columns as arguments.